# How to find database name from Apex URL

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex

I have access to the apex admin but i could not recall the database name under which the apex url is running.
Is there any way to get the database name from apex url

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Apex Admin, I guess you also have access to (at least) one of workspaces. If not, you can always create one for you.

So:

- pick any of those workspaces
- connect as a developer
- go to SQL Workshop's **SQL Commands**
- run the following statements; at least one should *work* and reveal that information

  ```
  select * from global_name;

  select sys_context('USERENV', 'DB_NAME') from dual;

  select name from V$database;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The apex url does not contain any information about the database name. Apex uses ORDS to map the http request to a database call and it is in the ORDS configuration file that that the database information is entered (hostname, port, service_name, username)